# could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider> & I have already provided the provider wrapper

Tags: react-native

```
const RootNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#EE4254" />
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={Store.store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={Store.persistor}>
        <RootNavigation />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

// I have already provided the Provider but i don't know why asking for provider wrapper

Comment: Here is a simple  react redux example https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter?file=/src/app/store.js . Try to integrate it in your app from scratch and you will have working redux in project